# Data annotation and wpf validation

Tags: wpf, validation, data-annotations

Is there any way that I use data annotation as the source of validation in WPF? I want to be able to define a class such as:

```
class myData
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

And then bind it to a field in a view and the wpf validate that user enter some value for this field and also make sure that its length is not greater than 50. I know that I can write a validator for this, but then if I change the maxLength to say 60, then I need to change it in validator and I don't want to have changes in different places.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a "metadata" definition of the class. You'll need something like this:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(MyClass.MyClassMetadata))]
public partial class MyClass
{
    internal sealed class MyClassMetadata
    {
        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private MyClassMetadata()
        {
        }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

This extends the class with the necessary meta data to support the validation.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please lead me to some sample or more documentation in what should put in metadata and how to setup validation in xaml?

Comment: My pleasure... I wish WPF had taken Annotations seriously and also the had nvested time with PropertyDescriptors. Looks like `Attribute` based data management is slow.

Comment: @AngelWPF, Thanks for the reference. I went throught it and I think I can not use this with EF code first. Can I do this? I want to define my classes and then use them as the model for data persistance in EF. Any way that I can do this?

Comment: Whats the issue? Why cant you annotate fields of persiatance model classes from EF?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is still left unanswered and I came across it while answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30720865/2310818) that was looking for the same thing, I would share the solution of that question over here too.

The Microsoft TechNet article "[Data Validation in MVVM](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22660.data-validation-in-mvvm.aspx#Merging_Validation_and_PropertyChanged_Notification)" is a very clean and thorough implementation of using Data Annotations for validation in WPF. I read through the solution myself and would recommend it to others.