# Custom ValidationAttribute doesn't work. Always returns true

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I've created a custom ValidationAttribute class to check the age of a person in my application:

```
public class MinimumAgeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int MinAge { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return CalculateAge((DateTime) value) >= MinAge;
    }

    private int CalculateAge(DateTime dateofBirth)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        int age = today.Year - dateofBirth.Year;
        if (dateofBirth > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
        return age;
    }
}
```

The data annotation is set on the field like this:

```
[MinimumAge(MinAge = 18, ErrorMessage = "Person must be over the age of 18")]   
public DateTime DateOfBirth;
```

The binding in my UI is set like this:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedPerson.DateOfBirth, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

When I set the date (for example) to 09/06/2007 for example, `Validator.TryValidateObject` always returns true.

Why? This only seems to affect my custom classes, all the ones provided in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations work fine.

Comment: Not sure this will resolve your issue, but while dealing with dates always consider culture you convert to and from. You have a direct cast from `object`  to `DateTime`.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to see what the values of the variables are? What does `CalculateAge` return for your example date?

Comment: Perhaps this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665290/validate-age-according-to-date-of-birth-using-model-in-mvc-4/29692850#29692850

Comment: @Ron CalculateAge never gets called.

Comment: From the code you have shown above, I am assuming that you are using WPF. Is this correct?

Comment: @Parth, yes, it's WPF, with EF and following the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @Jake, I found another post asking a similar question but it isn't answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820588/data-annotation-and-wpf-validation. Perhaps you could try to get in touch with that user to see how they went about solving the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your custom ValidationAttribute class isn't working is because WPF doesn't (by default) look into such classes when doing validation. The default mechanism for validation is implementing the IDataErrorInfo (available for .NET 4.0 and earlier) or INotifyDataErrorInfo (introduced in .NET 4.5)  interfaces. If you don't want to implement any of those interfaces, then you can create a ValidationRule, but I prefer implementing the interfaces mentioned above.

You can find a lot of examples on how to do this online, but doing a quick search found this [blog post](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/) (which on a quick scan I felt was very thorough).

---

### EDIT

Since you seemed more keen on using Data Annotations instead of IDataErrorInfo/INotifyDataErrorInfo interfaces or Validation Rule, I think the Microsoft TechNet article ["Data Validation in MVVM"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22660.data-validation-in-mvvm.aspx#Merging_Validation_and_PropertyChanged_Notification) is a very clean and thorough implementation of using Data Annotations for validation. I read through the solution myself and would recommend it to others.

Comment: I've looked at that post before and others like it. But I keep fighting with myself about if I'm implementing that correctly as I've ended up with 200+ line indexers and methods and 40+ classes that all do the same thing just with slight syntactical differences.

Comment: @Jake, sorry to hear about that. But did you try using ValidationRule. It seemed quite close to ValidationAttribute for data validation functionality that you would need across different classes. Otherwise indexers and methods are the suggested way to go about it.

Comment: If I'm thinking of the ValidationRule class you're thinking of, this again would have ended up with a namespace containing about 40 classes, which just seems like bad programming practice to me, unless I'm missing the point?

Comment: I was thinking of a CustomValidationRule that would act as an adapter to see whether the current attribute has a ValidationAttribute and if so, invoke the validation method of the ValidationAttribute. This would make your Data Binding statement much longer, because you will have to tell it to use the same ValidationRule resource, but it should do the job.

Comment: Alternately, I found this article on MSDN about how to use Data Annotations for validation in WPF: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22660.data-validation-in-mvvm.aspx#Merging_Validation_and_PropertyChanged_Notification which to me looks like an implementation of the idea which I have in my mind.

Comment: @Jake, if this article does the trick, please let me know as I would love to try it out myself in future projects. Thanks.